# How to access the react-router-redux URL params from within a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Given the following router:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider as StoreProvider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConnectedRouter} from 'react-router-redux';

const App = ({store}) => {
  return (
          <StoreProvider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path="/welcome/:welcomeId" layout={MainLayout} component={Welcome} />
              </Switch>
            </ConnectedRouter>
          </StoreProvider>
  );
};
```

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor');
    console.log(props.params);
  }
....
```

Why am I not getting `props.params` in the constructor?

Comment: FYI, my package.json:     "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the params can be accessed through the `props.match.params`